# bind добавление в переменную текста. Как посмотреть?

Tags: python, bind

Короче такой код:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

code = ""


def add_word(text):
    return code + text

root.bind("a", lambda code: add_word("a"))
print(code)

root.mainloop()
```

При нажатии на клавишу `a` он в переменную `code` добавляет одну букву `a`.
Но как мне посмотреть значение переменной? То есть как сделать так, чтобы после каждого нажатия на клавишу `a` она добавлялась в переменную `code` и + эта переменная `code` выводилась ко мне в консоль?